# DiffUtil payload data received on First viewType but I need second Viewtype

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I've used two viewType in RecyclerView Adapter Custom Class with DiffUtil.

In that I update data It will **update the Diffutil getChangePayload** but it updates first view type.

How to change payload data to **TYPE_ITEM** viewType?

```
> **CustomViewAdapter class**

  private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
  private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.home_list_items, parent, false);
                return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
            } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.home_banner, parent, false);
                return new HeaderView(itemView);
            }
            return null;
        }



    @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) { 
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: viewholder " + viewHolder);
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: payload " + payloads);
}
```

Comment: what is difference between this 2 type models????

Comment: Actually the First one inside one recycler view coming, Second View Type is the main layout of the page

Comment: It is possible to change payload data to particular viewType?

Comment: if your types model are different and can't cast to other one, you should create another diffUtils, or create generic diffUtils and check passed model instance

Comment: Where to pass the instance?                                                                         DiffUtil.DiffResult result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(
new HomeDiffCallback(homeItemList, homeItemListNew, ItemViewAdapter.TYPE_ITEM));
                result.dispatchUpdatesTo(itemAdapter);DiffUtil.DiffResult result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(
                        new HomeDiffCallback(homeItemList, homeItemListNew, ItemViewAdapter.TYPE_ITEM));
                result.dispatchUpdatesTo(itemAdapter); I passed this way early

Comment: Hai, It solved this one in the following way. setHasStableIds(true); (Inside constructor)     @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {;
            if (position > 0)
                return Long.parseLong(itemList.get(position-1).getId());
            else return super.getItemId(position);
        }

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case where you have 2 types of items listed *below* each other (not mixed), I recommend to use the `ConcatAdapter` from the RecyclerView package:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter

It allows you to connect 2 normal ViewAdapters - for each type one separate adapter. This keeps your codebase a lot cleaner and maintainable.

This is a short example how to use it:

```
 MyAdapter adapter1 = ...;
 AnotherAdapter adapter2 = ...;
 ConcatAdapter concatenated = new ConcatAdapter(adapter1, adapter2);
 recyclerView.setAdapter(concatenated);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomDiffUtil<T> extends DiffUtil.Callback{

List<T> oldData;
List<T> newData;

public CustomDiffUtil(List<T> oldData,List<T> newData) {
    this.newData = newData;
    this.oldData = oldData;
}

@Override
public int getOldListSize() {
    return oldData.size();
}

@Override
public int getNewListSize() {
    return newData.size();
}

@Override
public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
    return oldData.get(oldItemPosition) == newData.get(newItemPosition);
}

@Override
public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
    return oldData.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newData.get(newItemPosition));
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getChangePayload(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
    //you can return particular field for changed item.
    return super.getChangePayload(oldItemPosition, newItemPosition);
}
```

}